# JavaFX: Exception => java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, exception, shared-libraries, pdfbox

I'm new in building and deploying java applications.
I developed an application which should create an pdf-document. For this purpose I use the **pdfbox-library** from [apache](https://pdfbox.apache.org/).   For building the application I use **ant.**

If I run the application on my IDE(Luna 4.4) no errors . But after building it and running the **.jar** on my pc or another pc, I get the following exception:

> **Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pdfbox/encoding/                           EncodingManager
>           at helper.MyHelper.getSpecialCharacter(Unknown Source)
>           at helper.MyHelper.formatString(Unknown Source)
>           at controller.InvoiceC.fillView(Unknown Source)
>           at controller.InvoiceC$MyTabListener.changed(Unknown Source)
>           at controller.InvoiceC$MyTabListener.changed(Unknown Source)
>           at** com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361)
>           at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
>           at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyO                           bjectWrapper.java:176)
>           at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:142                           )
>           at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
>           at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
>           at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(SelectionModel.java:102)
>           at javafx.scene.control.TabPane$TabPaneSelectionModel.select(TabPane.java:717)
>           at javafx.scene.control.TabPane$TabPaneSelectionModel.select(TabPane.java:735)
>           at javafx.scene.control.TabPane$TabPaneSelectionModel.select(TabPane.java:656)
>           at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TabPaneBehavior.selectTab(TabPaneBehavior.java:122)
>           at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TabPaneSkin$TabHeaderSkin$5.handle(TabPaneSkin.java:1332)
>           at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TabPaneSkin$TabHeaderSkin$5.handle(TabPaneSkin.java:1317)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.jav                           a:59)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
>           at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
>           at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
>           at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
>           at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
>           at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler                           .java:352)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler                           .java:275)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(GlassViewEventHandle                           r.java:388)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pdfbox.encoding.EncodingManager
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           ... 50 more

---

Following the [guide](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/dependencies.html) I added all required libraries into my project.

[image: libs]

---

Here you can see the code, which is responsible for the exception:

```
public static String formatString(float value) {
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");
String s = String.valueOf(df.format(value));

try {
       s+= " " +getSpecialCharacter();
            switch(s.length()) {
                case 5: s = "         " +s; 
                    break;
                case 6: s = "       " +s;
                    break;
                case 7: s = "     " +s; 
                    break;
                case 8: s = "   " +s; 
                    break;

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return s;
}

public static String getSpecialCharacter() throws IOException {
    Encoding e = EncodingManager.INSTANCE.getEncoding(COSName.WIN_ANSI_ENCODING);
    return String.valueOf(Character.toChars(e.getCode("Euro")));
}
```

---

I'm really confused, I hope someone will help me!!

Comment: How about using one single version and not several different ones at the same time? All you need is the file pdfbox-app-1.8.10.jar. The guide does not advice to use 1.8.7, 1.8.8 and 1.8.10 together.

Comment: I added the file _pdfbox-app-1.8.10.jar_ to my project and remove all the others, but I've got the same problem like above.

Comment: sorry to hear that. Next thing to do would be to inspect the jar of your project (e.g. with 7zip) to see whether org/apache/pdfbox/encoding/ is present.

Comment: I looked into the jar and the org/apache/pdfbox/encoding is in there. The guide advice to run _mvn dependency:copy-dependencies_ inside the pdfbox directory. How can I manage this??

Comment: mvn requires you to install maven.

Comment: I'm confused. In the jar the required org/apache/pdfbox/encoding is available and in the IDE it works fine. But in runtime it crashes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99938/discussion-between-ramazan86-and-tilman-hausherr).

Comment: I entered to the chat ...

Answer (score 0):

@Tilman Hausherr helped me to solve my problem.
I solved my issue with the following steps:

1. add pdfbox-app.1.8.10 to my project
2. run my builded jar, on that location where my added jars is

Comment: You had to create a "libs" subdirectory in the directory where your main jar is, and copy the jar files there. (Based on the class-path in the MANIFEST.MF file in the jar)